# Removing a Policy Tag from Bigquery table using Terraform

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-gcp

I am setting Policy Tags on my Bigquery Schema using terraform but when I try to remove it, it doesn't work and stays on.

Policy tags are added in the following way. I am including them in Schema in create table resource and it works perfectly.

```
   {
  "fields": [
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "Email",
      "type": "STRING",
      "policyTags":{
        "names": [
          "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}/policyTags/${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id}"
          ]
      }
    },
    {
      "mode": "NULLABLE",
      "name": "Mobile",
      "type": "STRING",
      "policyTags":{
        "names": [
          "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}/policyTags/${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id}"
          ]
      }
    },
```

}

But if I remove the PolicyTags i-e just remove following lines and apply my Terraform template, it doesn't throw any error or exception and says 1 change is made but when I move to GCP console the Policy tag is still on

```
  "policyTags":{
    "names": [
      "projects/my_project/locations/europe-west2/taxonomies/${google_data_catalog_taxonomy.my_taxonomy.id}/policyTags/${google_data_catalog_policy_tag.PII.id}"
      ]
  }
```

My assumption / idea is we need to remove the PolicyTag link from Taxonomy but HOW that I couldn't find in any of the documentation. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In the schema, the "policyTags" field value needs to be changed as below
"""

```
{
 "fields": [
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "Email",
  "type": "STRING",
  "policyTags":{
    "names": []
  }
},
{
  "mode": "NULLABLE",
  "name": "Mobile",
  "type": "STRING",
  "policyTags":{
    "names": []
  }
}
```

Storing this JSON into a file as anything.json and executing the below command

`bq update PROJECT_ID:DATASET.TABLENAME anything.json`

Comment: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/column-level-security#bq_1